# How to add facebook like icon in detail view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, interface-builder, ios-4.2

I am working on a navigation based app. every cell has a detail view. i have textView in detail view which shows details of selected cell. is it possible to add a facebook like icon in the end of textView? and if no then how should i do that. thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the icon after the textview, or you can overlay it on top of the textview.   It's as simple as putting it there in interface builder:

[image]

or, just set the frame properties of the text view and the image view to overlap, and place the image view on top of the text view (simplest way is just to "addSubview" it 2nd, which will place it on top).

Comment: infact i have three textViews in scroll view. and i want facebook like icon in the last. can u tell me how to make the image view to overlap the textView. is it just like to drag and drop on textView on some position then it ll b done automatically? and how to attach a link with that image. that if i click that image it should open some link in safari. thanx